# ImageView exceeds parent android studio xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

How do I make a child `ImageView` clip to the bounds of its parent?  When I add an ImageView as a child to a parent view with rounded corners, the child ImageView does not conform to the rounded corners.

I have tried:
`android:cropToPadding`
`android:clipChildren`
`android:clipToPadding`
`android:adjustViewBounds`

I have set these to true and false on the image view and the parent view, and all possible combinations.

I have a custom view: `custom_view.xml` for rounded corners

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:backgroundTint="@color/backgroundColor" android:radius="10dp" />
  <solid android:color="@color/backgroundBlue" />
</shape>
```

[image]

I have a fragment, `fragment_card.xml` that implements the custom view.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_view"   <-- setting the custom_view
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardIconView"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/line_separator"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
and it continues...
```

The child ImageView does not clip to the bounds of the parent view with the custom background. Notice the left corners are not rounded

[image]

`CardListAdapter`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) { 
  holder.cardIconView.setImageDrawable(theimage)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So there is a little bit of misunderstanding happening here in your question. The first thing I want to address is your assumption:

> "When I add an ImageView as a child to a parent view with rounded corners, the child ImageView does not conform to the rounded corners."

Your child view is in fact respecting the bounds of the parent view. The rounded corners are *not* the bounds of the parent `View`, but the clipping of the drawable that is inside the `View`. What you refer to as your custom view, the `custom_view.xml` file, is in fact a custom drawable that is applied as the background to the parent. It has no impact on the bounds of the `ConstraintLayout`.

If you would like your image to also have rounded corners, I would encourage you to find a tutorial on clipping the source of an `ImageView`. Googling for this finds several easy tutorials, including one from Romain Guy, as well as several on Medium that will do the trick for you.

To recap: your child view is in fact respecting the bounds of the parent, the background you are applying to the view is not in fact the bounds of the parent, only a drawable to act as a background within the bounds of the parent view. Thus, you will need to perform some type of masking or clipping on the image or build a custom `ImageView` class that auto clips its content.

Comment: Perhaps then you can give a real solution to this, I need something similar to the OP

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by real solution? I have provided context to explain the misunderstandings in the OP's question/assumptions, and then provided direction regarding solving it. I have not written any code because there is already an exhaustive list of resources on clipping an imageview on Google, and I am not going to link to a specific tutorial because I do not want to be promoting a particular source. While I do mention Romain Guy, because he is close to being 1st party source at Google, his tutorial is old, and do not want to hard link to it.

Comment: I mean to edit your answer and add a solution because all the SO questions I've seen regarding this do not have working solutions.

Comment: There are plenty of working tutorials and OSL's for making rounded imageviews if you just search on google.

Comment: Then looks like this question should be closed for **lack of research**- Why is it still here?

Comment: Sure. That's fine. However, while there is a lack of research, there is also a lack of understanding in the asker's assumptions, and this answer serves as an answer to those misunderstandings.

Comment: No, in fact, jungledev knows this. He just said that the ImageView doesn't clip to the bounds of the background drawable of the parent. He _just wants a solution_. See Raaaaac's answer and the comments below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `android:clipToOutline="true"` on parent view or programatically `cardView.setClipToOutline(true);`

Answer (score 0):

I also have encountered this problem and found a solution. You can wrap the contents in a `CardView` and set `cardCornerRadius` to achieve the desired effect. Example:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">
    ...
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This will force children to respect parent's corner radius.

Answer (score -1):

The ImageView is actually meeting the constraints you set. That is **because the bounds of the parent don't change.**
Here's a solution: include a margin to the ImageView combined with `match_parent` width a height, in order to make it fit the rounded parent leaving a little border in the sides. Play with the margin dimension (in dp) until you get what you are looking for.

Comment: Not really what people need... Playing with a dimension in one screen size will make it look bad in another.

Comment: Not at all what I need.  By saying "The ImageView is actually meeting the constraints you set" is useless.  This has nothing to do with the question.  If you have found a solution then please post a code snippet and screenshot showing your solution.

Comment: @jungledev You said :
The child ImageView does not clip to the bounds of the parent view with the custom background. 
Raaaaac just stated that custom backgrounds don't clip the child views.

Comment: I'm not saying he's wrong. I'm saying this isn't an _answer_ therefore not what I need... What I _need_ is to round the corners of the icon, not to shrink the square icon such that it fits in the rounded corners of a parent.

Answer (score -1):

You can create another left_corner.xml and apply it to child ImageView, try this:

```
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:backgroundTint="@color/backgroundColor" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
      <solid android:color="@color/backgroundBlue" />
    </shape>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not work.  If you set the ImageView's `background="@drawable/left_corner.xml"` and the `src="@drawable/the_icon"` it doesn't work.  Have you tried this and gotten it to work somehow?